# PowerShell sort works fine on some machines but not others

Tags: powershell, sorting

I'm not well-versed with PowerShell and I have been trying to sort the output for the code below:

```
function Get-DirSize ($path) { 

    BEGIN {} 

    PROCESS{ 
        $colItems = Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object

        foreach ($folder in $colItems)
        {
            $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject 
            $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
            $sizeGB="{0:N4}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum/1GB)   
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Folder" -Value $folder.FullName
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Size(GB)" -Value $sizeGB 
            $object 
        } 
    }
    END {} 
}

Get-DirSize -path 'C:\' |
Sort-Object 'Size(GB)' -Descending
```

I am able to get a sorted output on my desktop, but somehow the same code does not give me a sorted output on my laptop (as seen below for my laptop output).

[PSSortedOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsoqx.png)

Does anyone know why this may be happening? Or is there something I should be changing to the code itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than posting an image you should have simply copied the output into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$sizeGB="{0:N4}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum/1GB)
```

converts `($subFolderItems.sum/1GB)` into a string and stores it in a variable named "sizeGB".

Then on this line:

```
Sort-Object 'Size(GB)' -Descending
```

You are sorting that string in descending order. So you are performing a lexical sort (A.K.A alphabetical order) of strings of numbers. If you look at your results you will see they are sorted alphabetically in descending order (e.g. the string starting with '6' comes before the string starting with '5' which comes before the string starting with '4' etc.).

So don't prematurely convert your numbers to strings for the purposes of formatting. Formatting objects returned from your function is antithetical to the idea of PowerShell anyway. You want to deal with objects all the way through, from start to finish. The final consumer should be the one that decides how the output should be formatted.

Comment: I see! I didn't know that changed it to a string. It finally makes sense. Apologies, this must have been a very basic problem. Appreciate the help!